# Save PDF file in Downloads folder in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

In my method in controller I use the following code to save pdf.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);
            HtmlNode node = doc.GetElementbyId("DetailsToPDF");
            HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
            var pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf("<html><body>" + node.InnerHtml + "</body></html>");

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=TEST.pdf");
            Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

Everything has passed without any exceptions in debugger. However file is not saved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't actually save the file. It'll only ask your browser to handle the file. Depending on how the browser is configured it might save it, it might display it

Comment: Browser(Chrome) didn't show anything. Where should I configure it?

Comment: Actually you're writing the file contents to the HTTP response using `BinaryWrite`, it doesn't returning any file to download. Try to return `FileResult`/`FileContentResult`, which showing option to open or download the file in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to return a File in ASP.NET MVC is using the `File()` helper method:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
  // Starting with pdfBytes here...
  // ...
  var pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf("<html><body>" + node.InnerHtml + "</body></html>");
  var contentDisposition = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
  {
      FileName = "TEST.pdf",
      Inline = false
  };
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
  return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: In this solution, can I set encoding on UTF.8?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for that? The PDF file has it's own encoding, the File result is returning only the bytes. If you get some malformed characters, the issue might lie somewhere in the PDF generation process itself. But you can still try to call `Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` or `Response.Charset = "utf-8";`and see if it helps

Comment: Reason: Polish letters :)

Comment: It doesn't help.

Comment: Should I use special font and implement in your solution?

Comment: I don't think so. If your PDF doesn't show polish characters right, then you should check the possibilities of the htmlToPdf tool (I don't know which tool you're using). I think that the problem lies there, between conversion of source html (`node.InnerHtml`) and the output from the htmlToPdf tool

Comment: I use NReco tool.

Comment: So maybe you just need to put the Encoding into the HTML Text? After _<html>_ and before _<body>_ in the code above, put: `<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>`. If it doesn't work, check if the "node.InnerHtml" (I don't know where it's coming from) has the right letters

Comment: Yes, a few hours ago I thought about it.;)

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/files/newPDFFile.pdf");
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);
    if (buffer != null)
    {

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "PDFfile.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        Response.End();
    }
```